# Transform Based Animation using Vue Transition Wrapper

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to port some animation implemented mostly through `css` and little `javascript` to a `Vue` component. The animation is simple - user clicks a button and a little panel opens from the bottom of his browser and slides upwards.

I have a working `Vue` component implemented using the same `css` and no `javascript`.

Now, I'm aware of the `transition` wrapper that `Vue` provides. But I'm unable to figure out how to get similar functionality using the `transition` wrapper (if at all).

Can someone help me out here?

```js
// register modal component
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  props: ['show']
})

// start app
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showModal: false
  }
})
```

```css
.drawer-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 9998;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}

.drawer-wrapper.open {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.drawer-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.drawer-header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #42b983;
}

.drawer-body {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.drawer-default-button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- template for the modal component -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
        <div class="drawer-wrapper" :class="{ open: show }">
            <div class="drawer-container">

                <div class="drawer-header">
                    <slot name="header">
                        default header
                    </slot>
                </div>

                <div class="drawer-body">
                    <slot name="body">
                        default body
                    </slot>
                </div>

                <div class="drawer-footer">
                    <slot name="footer">
                        default footer
                        <button class="drawer-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                            OK
                        </button>
                    </slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</script>

<!-- app -->
<div id="app">
  <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
  <!-- use the modal component, pass in the prop -->
  <modal @close="showModal = false" :show="showModal">
    <!--
      you can use custom content here to overwrite
      default content
    -->
    <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
  </modal>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using a `transition` wrapper, but the code isn't as elegant as I'd expected. Particularly the use of the following attributes in the `drawer-wrapper` class:

```
top: 100%;
transform: translateY(-100%);
```

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gmanish/pk56nfo6/3/)

If anyone can simplify the code further, I'd really appreciate it.